# White NDS drain PVC pipe next to trees?

Tags: plumbing, water

I frequently see white PVC pipes sticking out of the ground near trees. Normally it's one, like by the tree on my property, but sometimes there's even two:

[image]

A closer look at the pipe reveals it's an NDS sewer & drain pipe.

[image]

What are these? Obviously not sewer, and they don't look like they drain anything. They look a little like DIY solutions I've seen before to get water deeper underneath the tree to train its roots to go down to look for water instead of up & destroying the landscape, but not quite since it looks difficult to pry off the cap. Is that what these are? Why would they need two for this?

Answer (score 2):

Either:

to put water in to the roots when it was younger or:

it was for the posts used to protect it when it was small.

Both are valid but may not be the "real" reason...

Comment: This answer is 100% correct.  I'll add that a lot of times, trees that are maintained by muni or commercial/HOAs often run the drip irrigation tubes directly into those sleeves to keep evaporation to a minimum.